# Get default datetime form on Symfony 2 twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

i have some probleme, i would like to have a default value in my datetime twig, i dont want to have the defaut value from BuildForm cause i use it for other twigs.

My add twig

```
     <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.Url, "Le URL", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-4 textTab control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.Url) }}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          {{ form_widget(form.Url, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.dateDeLaDemande, "Date de la demande du crawl", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-4 textTab control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.dateDeLaDemande) }}
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 8px;">
          {{ form_widget(form.dateDeLaDemande, {'attr': {'class': 'col-sm-6'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        {{ form_label(form.DateDuCrawl, "Date du crawl", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-4 textTab control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.DateDuCrawl) }}
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 8px;">
          {{ form_widget(form.DateDuCrawl, {'attr': {'class': 'col-sm-6' }}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my buildFom

```
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
              ->add('site','text')


              ->add('Url','url')
              ->add('dateDeLaDemande','date')
              ->add('DateDuCrawl','date')
              ->add('DateNextCrawl','date')                    
              ->add('faitVP', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
              ->add('integrerMavec','checkbox', array('required' => false))                    
//            ->add('historique','textarea')
              ->add('historiques', 'collection', array(
                        'type'         => new CategoryType(),
                        'allow_add'    => true,
                        'allow_delete' => true
                      ))
              ->add('save','submit') 
    ;
}
```

Can some one help me plz ? thanks and sorry about my english :)

Comment: I cannot understand what you need. Add some details. You need default value for class? value for form field? value for twig template? object ?

Comment: Value for the formfield, the datetime one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
{{ form_widget(form.form.dateDeLaDemande, {value : currentDate}) }}
```

To declare a variable in twig :

```
{% set currentDate = "now"|date("m/d/Y")  %}
```

or directely :

```
 {{ form_widget(form.form.dateDeLaDemande, {value : "now"|date("m/d/Y")}) }}
```

Comment: That does set my date on a default value, maybe because its a string not a datetime ?